# fiona ImportError: ... Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.91.dylib

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geopandas, fiona

I reinstalled Anaconda (Anaconda 3, Python 3.9) on my Mac (MacOs Monterey 12.2) today. I installed `geopandas` through **conda-forge** and imported it successfully in Python of my **base** environment (3.9.12). I then installed `salem` through **conda-forge** too and its import in Python failed, returning:

```
>>> import salem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/salem/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from salem.datasets import *
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/salem/datasets.py", line 32, in <module>
    from salem import utils, gis, wrftools, sio, check_crs
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/salem/utils.py", line 88, in <module>
    hash_cache_dir = _hash_cache_dir()
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/salem/utils.py", line 55, in _hash_cache_dir
    import geopandas
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from geopandas.io.file import _read_file as read_file  # noqa
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 14, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Reading this, I tried to import `fiona` by itself in a new console and it gave me this error message:

```
>>> import fiona
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
  File "/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 11, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.91.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/libgdal.30.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/../../../libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/../../../libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpoppler.91.dylib' (no such file)
```

I don't have much experience with management of Conda packages. When I run `conda list` I get the following (abridged):

```
conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/felixlangot/opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               hd59e818_1    conda-forge
branca                    0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            h0ab9d94_1001    conda-forge
cftime                    1.6.0            py39h86b5767_1    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
conda                     4.12.0           py39h6e9494a_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.4.4                he49afe7_0    conda-forge
fiona                     1.8.21           py39haa9df5e_0    conda-forge
folium                    0.12.1.post1       pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.94              h10f422b_0    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.6                h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
geopandas-base            0.10.2             pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
geos                      3.8.0                h4a8c4bd_1    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h7937167_1005    conda-forge
glib                      2.68.4               he49afe7_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.68.4               he49afe7_0    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            hefd3b78_1005    conda-forge
json-c                    0.13.1            h575e443_1002    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.14               h31dd65d_2    conda-forge
libdap4                   3.19.1            hae55d67_1000    conda-forge
libglib                   2.68.4               hd556434_0    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             hed7d534_1010    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a            h9691d84_1033    conda-forge
libzip                    1.8.0                h8b0c345_1    conda-forge
mapclassify               2.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 he49afe7_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.38.0            h01d97ff_1003    conda-forge
poppler                   0.89.0               hd735947_5    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.11               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
proj                      6.2.1                h773a61f_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
salem                     0.3.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tiledb                    2.2.9                he9a4fb4_0    conda-forge
xyzservices               2022.4.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

I only included **conda-forge** packages because my post was too long to be accpeted otherwise. I can provide the full output of `conda list` if needed. Nevertheless, the packages seem to be all there.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you for your help.

#### Additional Info

I also tried

```bash
conda create -n test
conda activate test
conda install -c conda-forge fiona
```

and the installation was again successful. However, `import fiona` in Python of **test** environment still gives the same error message.

##### Related Issue

This post on GitHub seems to treat a very similar issue: https://github.com/conda-forge/geopandas-feedstock/issues/64. However, it is from 2019 and was closed before the problem was fixed, so it did not help me.

Comment: Maybe try installing at the same time as creating the new env? `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge python=3.9 geopandas`

Comment: I would suggest installing all required packages at the same time, e.g. `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge python=3.9 geopandas salem fiona`

Comment: Thanks you @MichaelDelgado and @jsta! Installing all packages at the same time in a new environment appears to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give the same advice as on the GitHub issue and which Conda Forge has [in their documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels): *don't mix channels*. Channel mixing is the most common cause of all dynamic library issues.

#### No issue with Conda Forge only

Creating an environment from scratch with the YAML

[image: so-fiona]

**so-fiona.yaml**

```yaml
name: so-fiona
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - fiona
  - salem
```

and `conda env create -f so-fiona.yaml`, works fine on all major platforms.

Comment: Thank you, @merv. I did something similar that worked. I was trying to install those packages in my `base` environment, which already had packages installed by default.

Comment: Yeah, one is better off not using **base** for work.